# how to write a junit using mockito for this method alogorithm?

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, mockito

Hi I am tryint to write a junit using mockito for the below algorithm. can you please help me.

```
public void setOrientation(Activity activity) {
    Get the DisplayMetrics for the phone;
    calculate the screen size;
    get configurations;
    
    if (diagonalInches>=6.5 && tablet connected to hard keyboard){
        set screen orientation
    }
}
```

Comment: Make mocks of other classes this method uses.  Call the method in your test, then verify that the right methods have been invoked in the mocked classes.  Assert that any values in the activity variable are whatever they should be.  If that's not enough help, please provide the actual code so we have a better idea of what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Create Activity Object with all required values

Step 2 : Create mockBeans for all the @Autowired using @MockBean

Step 3 : Create @Test method

Step 4 : Call method using class object using Activity object

Step 5 : Mock all the outside or bean calls using Mockito.when(mock.methodTOMock).then(mockedReturnValue);

Step 6 : Verify methods instance are called and how many times they are called using

Mockito.verify(mockObject, time(number)).methodTOtest(arguments/Matcher methods);

Step 7 : Verify expected and actual return values
using Assert()

can you provide sample code here so that we can get better understanding